# Whether all operations in WPF is synchronous or asynchronous by default ?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, asynchronous, synchronous

I am new to the WPF. I know that silverlight is asynchronous by default. I want to know whether all operations in WPF is synchronous or asynchronous by default ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight is a different (branch of the) framework, and it only has asynchronous versions of most methods.

WPF is part of the base .NET framework and you can use the full range of synchronous library methods as well as the asynchronous versions. For performance the async ones should be favored.

Comment: means WPF is synchrnous by default. isn't it ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with  'by default', and what part(s) you refer to.

Comment: @ShaileshJaiswal: If you call the synchronous methods, then they're synchronous. If you call the asynchronous methods, then they're asynchronous. There is no default; it's your choice.